# Text placeholder for currency input using Inputmask

Tags: jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I want to have a text placeholder for a currency input field using Input mask.

When the input value is empty, I want to display "Other" but as soon as the user begins typing it should mask the input to US dollars.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#otheramount').inputmask({
    alias: 'currency',
    digits: 2,
    rightAlign: 0
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input id="otheramount" placeholder="Other" name="otheramount" data-_extension-text-contrast="" type="text">
```

The [placeholder](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#placeholder) option is for masked input characters not for when the value of the input is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [clearMaskOnLostFocus](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/tree/0d3363e1b2ed5649eddd50074329916da01e39bd#clearmaskonlostfocus) option

```js
$(function() {
  $('#otheramount').inputmask({
    alias: 'currency',
    digits: 2,
    rightAlign: 0,
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: true
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<input id="otheramount" placeholder="Other" name="otheramount" data-_extension-text-contrast="" type="text">
```